# Identifier … has already been declared

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, postman

I'm building a social network to learn nodejs and reactjs. Currently while building the backend in the `/signin` debug with postman I can't even launch the node server, the cmd throws the following error:

```
\node_react\2\nodeapi\controllers\auth.js:40
const {_id, name, email} = user;
          ^
SyntaxError: Identifier 'email' has already been declared
```

The code snippet which throws the error is the following:

```
//generate a token with user id and secret
const token = jwt.sign({_id: user._id}, process.env.JWT_SECRET);

//persist the token as 't' in cookie with expiry date
res.cookie("t", token, {expire: new Date() + 9999});

//return response with user and token to frontend client
const {_id, name, email} = user;
return res.json({token, user:{_id, email, name}});
```

The complete auth.js code is the following :

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
require ('dotenv').config();
const User = require("../models/user");

exports.signup = async (req, res) => {
    const userExists = await User.findOne({email: req.body.email});
    if(userExists) 
        return res.status(403).json({
            error: "Email is taken!"
        }); 
    const user = await new User(req.body);
    await user.save();
    res.status(200).json({ message: "Signup success! Please login:)" });
};

exports.signin = (req,res) => {
    //find the user based on email
    const { email, password } = req.body 
    User.findOne({email}, (err, user) => {
        //if error or no user
        if (err || !user) {
            return res.status(401).json({
                error: "User with that email does not exists. Please signin."
            });
        }
        //if user is found make sure the email and password match
        // create authenticate method in model and use here
        if (!user.authenticate(password))
            return res.status(401).json({
                error: "Email and password do not match."
            });
    })

    //generate a token with user id and secret
    const token = jwt.sign({_id: user._id}, process.env.JWT_SECRET);

    //persist the token as 't' in cookie with expiry date
    res.cookie("t", token, {expire: new Date() + "9999"});
    //return response with user and token to frontend client
    const {_id, name, email} = user;
    return res.json({token, user:{_id, email, name}});      
}
```

Comment: It seems you have defined `email` before this assignment. Can you please provide all the `auth.ts` code?

Comment: Unrelated but `new Date() + 9999` is going to be string concatenation not arithmetic.

Comment: Added auth.js code @GustavoLopes

Comment: Im my case I was exporting something I imported... with the same name... just do `export { curry as curry }` for that. The logic is that external dependencies can be globally extended, swapped and replaced centrally without the need for refactoring.

Specific error: `SyntaxError: Identifier 'curry' has already been declared`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code, you're overriding the `email` variable, which was created with the `const` keyword (aka: can't be reassigned).

Jeena's answer probably solves the problem, but it seems you have a deeper problem.

`User.findOne({email}, (err, user){}` is async. So the code below this code will probably fail.

You PROBABLY have to rewrite your code as:

```
exports.signin = (req,res) => {
    //find the user based on email
    const { email, password } = req.body 
    User.findOne({email}, (err, user) => {
        //if error or no user
        if (err || !user) {
            return res.status(401).json({
                error: "User with that email does not exists. Please signin."
            });
        }
        //if user is found make sure the email and password match
        // create authenticate method in model and use here
        if (!user.authenticate(password))
            return res.status(401).json({
                error: "Email and password do not match."
            });

        //generate a token with user id and secret
        const token = jwt.sign({_id: user._id}, process.env.JWT_SECRET);

        //persist the token as 't' in cookie with expiry date
        res.cookie("t", token, {expire: new Date() + "9999"});
        //return response with user and token to frontend client
        const {_id, name, email} = user;
        return res.json({token, user:{_id, email, name}});      
    })
}
```

The `cookies` and `response` must be inside the MongoDB query, so you DO have the user.

Comment: Thank you very much/Muito Obrigado @GustavoLopes , this totally solved the problems

Comment: You're welcome. As best practices, try to always put brackets around `if`/`while` statements. It helps not to mess with identation.

Answer (score 2):

`const {_id, name, email} = user;` is called destructuring and will assign new variables with the same names of their objects.

So this:

```
const {_id, name, email} = user;
```

Is the same as:

```
const _id = user._id;
const name = user.name;
const email = user.email;
```

That's said, you're problably redefining `email` variable, which is set with the `const` keyword. It means you cannot reassign it.

What you can do is:

```
const {_id, name, email: _email} = user;
return res.json({token, user:{_id, name, email: _email}});
```

This will make the `email` field to be assigned to the `_email` variable, avoiding conflict.

Comment: Thank you @Jeena , this solved this problem, now the node server is already launched, but in signin debug with postman the cmd gives me the following :        
        ReferenceError: user is not defined
            at exports.signin 
        (C:\Users\luisc\node_react\2\nodeapi\controllers\auth.js:35:38)
            at Layer.handle [as handle_request] 
  
 
 
 
 
 
 (C:\Users\luisc\node_react\2\nodeapi\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95 
       :5)

Comment: Please, see my answer.